# Write a program to monitor Call Quality Matrics for particular time frame

Tags: java, python, algorithm, matrix

I have an interview task to do program. But, i am confused to understand the question in right manner.

Write the program to monitor call quality metrics for a duration of 1 min every 3 mins over a 1 hour (60 mins) time frame. i.e. Monitor 20 calls of 1 min duration each.

Your program should log data for the number of dropouts, clicks in audio and other relevant call quality metrics.

Implement your solution using Python. You may use any other supporting technologies in your solution.

What exactly interviewer want to do ?

Comment: What part do you not undestand? You are to sample audio streams, a minute of data each, every three minutes for an hour and log the data.

Comment: I have to implement this program in python or java.

Comment: I am not able to understand , whether i have to record stream every minute as buffer for 3 minute OR till 3 minutes ?

Comment: I was mainly targetting 'matrix' and 'algorithm'. Basically all tags as your question seems to be a logical, not a technical one and may be off topic here completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, I undestand your question as a matter of understanding the task decription.

You are to sample data from one stream for **one minute**, then wait two minutes, then select another stream for sampling and repeat, for **one hour**.

Comment: Actually, it's 'Jan'. Also, please conider using the accept and upvote buttons to say 'thank you' the SE way :)